# Populate an array in ruby with 7n +1

Tags: ruby, arrays

How do I make the following array programatically in Ruby (1.9).

It follows the pattern 7n + 1 and I'd like it to contain 24 numbers.

```
arr = ["8","15","22","29","36","43","50","57","64","71" ]
```

Comment: The `arr` you gave does not follow `7n+1`. What is the rule behind it?

Comment: you are correct, I've fixed it

Comment: Now it does not include 24 items.

Comment: please read the question properly before commenting, - I'd like it to contain 24 numbers (which it currently doesn't).

Comment: It does not say that it currently does not. When you display a code as an example output without explanation, it usually means that is what you want.

Comment: > it usually means that is what you want. Unless of course it says 'and I'd like it to'

Comment: Then what is that arr suppose to be showing? It is not the expected output, and you do not even have a failed code that outputs such arr. Then the arr is irrelevant to the question. What is the purpose for writing such irrelevant thing?

Comment: Sorry if you are confused. It seems that 'Ivaylo Strandjev' understood perfectly without all this complaining.

Comment: I am not confused. You are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `collect` and apply `to_s` on the result:

```
(1..24).collect{|n| (n*7 + 1).to_s}
```

EDIT: sorry forgot to convert numbers to strings. Code is edited now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.new(24){|i| (i * 7 + 8).to_s}
```